# Port redirection in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, port, redirect

I have a two server(running on two different port), one is for chat application, and another is for  API generation server(user should register by providing company
 details,and my algorithm gives a API key to the user).

The problem is, i am checking the valid API key,provided by the user, if API key is true then it should redirect to chat server(port no 5200).

But it doesn't work, please give any idea to resolve this issues.

Here is my code,

`

```
app.post('/checkAPIkey',function(req,res){
        var apikey=req.query.apikey;

        var apikey1=uuidAPIkey.isAPIKey(apikey);
        if(apikey1){
            res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: 'http://localhost:5200'
});
        }else{
            res.end("error");
        }

});`
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is called Request Forwarding.

**Example:**

```
const http = require('http');

app.post('/checkAPIkey', function(req,res){
    var apikey=req.query.apikey;

    var apikey1 = uuidAPIkey.isAPIKey(apikey);
    if(apikey1){
        const options = {
            port: NEW_PORT,
            hostname: 'NEW_HOST',
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/'
         };
        var reqForward = http.request(options, (newResponse) => {
                //Do something with your newResponse
                var responseData = "";
                newResponse.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    //Add data response from newResponse
                    responseData += chunk;
                });

                newResponse.on('end', () => {
                    //Nothing more, send it with your original Response
                    response.send(responseData);
                });
        });

        // If ERROR
        reqForward.on('error', (e) => {
             console.error('Error: ' + e);
        });

        // Write to the request
        reqForward.write(YOUR_POST_DATA);
        reqForward.end();
    } else {
        res.end("error");
    }
});
```